# How to setup Tomcat Server configuration in IntelliJ IDEA 13 to build Gradle project before deployment?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-13

I have Gradle project. I'm trying to configure Tomcat Server deployment configuration under IntelliJ IDEA 13. I would like to build the project before the deployment automatically. I do not see Gradle in the "Before launch" section. I added `gradle build` there as an "External tool", but I'm wondering if there is any better way to achieve this. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in IntelliJ IDEA 14 there is an option "Run Gradle task" under "Before lunch" so the problem is solved there. I'm not sure but I guess the project should be also set up as a Gradle project in the IDE.